# Creating Processes in Linux using fork() Function

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, compiler-flags

I've been trying to compile a piece of `C` code which should create processes using the `fork()` function.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    int n=15, z=20, count=3, mult=1;
    while(count<3)
    {
        if(z!=0)
        {
            z=fork();
            n=n+15;
        }
        else
        {
            z=fork(); n=n+10; mult=mult*n;
        }
        printf(" z=%d   mult=%d",z,mult);
        count=count+1;
    }
}
```

Compiled with `"gcc -Wall -W -Werror main.c -o ProcessCreateC"` in the terminal. I'm getting error:

```
main.c:3:5: error: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Werror=return-type]
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:20:5: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Since I only have experience compiling in Windows and have little experience with `Linux`, I have no idea what is causing this. Any ideas??

Comment: Apart from the language-level errors, if you initialise `count = 3`, the `while(count<3)` loop won't run.

Comment: Don't forget the `\n` at end of `printf` format string (and perhaps even call `fflush(NULL);` before every `fork`). And you should test the result of `fork`; it can fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return 0;`or a similar expression that returns an integer, to the end of your main(), and change `main()` to `int main()`, and I think you will find that the code works fine.

When no return type is specified for main(), it defaults to int. Furthermore, with the compiler flags you have enabled, not specifying a type for main() causes an error.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the issue. The piece of code was given to me, so I assumed the problem was in how I went about compiling. Should have looked for the obvious.

Comment: Np - we all trip to these kind of small errors at least once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is twofold (since *all* warnings are errors):

1. `main` should return int, e.g. actually end with `return 0;`
2. you should be explicit about `main` returning int, i.e. write `int main(`, not just `main(`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the return type of the main function as void so gcc is defaulting it to an integer return value.

Since GCC follows the ANSI C standard, you have to specify the return type of main as int like:

```
int main()
{
    //Do stuff
     return 0;
}
```

It is important to remember standards used by compilers, else you will continue making these mistakes and spend more time debugging rather than doing something productive.

Comment: Thanks @QuentinPerez I was just trying to show the way to properly code in C. :)

Comment: One could argue that aspiration would include using -W -Wall -Werror... but I digress, as I get what you mean.

Comment: @Varagrawal: Not sure what you mean. `main()` returning `void` is not proper C, regardless of the error flags.